# How make/find a brush like this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I am trying to achieve a similar look like the one in minutephysics videos like below for a college project (both outline and filler as shown in image below) - can you help with making brushes like the ones below? (please see the image in it's full version to observe more details):

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: Photoshop contains sever "chalk-like" brushes by default.

Comment: @scott - Could you share the names of these brushes? I don't find them in Photoshop

Comment: @sergey - I did try a lot of brushes, but none of them were this subtle as shown in the image. I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: All one need do is *look* at the [Brush Presets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMnSJ.png) and then adjust settings as desired.

Comment: Making your strokes and fills to look the same in Photoshop will be difficult - real drawing tools are so much more responsive. Consider to use the same method as the maker of Minutephysics: https://youtu.be/YoQcg39Krvk